# <AdapterClass> either be declared abstract or implement abstract method onBindViewHolder(VH,int) in <AdapterClass>

Tags: java, android, android-viewholder

```
public class SubjectAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubjectHolder> {
private ArrayList<Subjects> subjectsArrayList=new ArrayList<Subjects>();
private  Context mContext;


public SubjectAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext=context;
    populateList();
    this.subjectsArrayList = subjectsArrayList;
}

public void populateList(){
//Populates subjectArrayList 
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SubjectHolder holder, int position, @NonNull List payloads) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads);
    Subjects subject=subjectsArrayList.get(position);
    holder.setSubjectName(subject.getSubjectCode());


}

@NonNull
@Override
public SubjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View cardView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_card,parent,false);
    SubjectHolder subjectHolder=new SubjectHolder(cardView);
    return subjectHolder;
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return subjectsArrayList.size();
}
```

}

I read answer to similar question , but it doesnt seem to work out.
SubjectHolder is a class , which holds TextView and GridView.
I was actually trying to get a view like this ,
[image]

Comment: You are overriding the 3-parameter form of `onBindViewHolder()`. That is fine (though optional). However, you also need to override the 2-parameter form of `onBindViewHolder()`, as that is an `abstract` method, and you cannot compile without it.

Comment: @commonsware Answer it and i would accept it , also can you suggest how should i build the shown view , mg technique is , using recylerview to render cardView , and using Gridview inside it. It seems bulk is there any easy way out?

Comment: I probably would go with what you have described, except using a `ConstraintLayout` instead of `GridView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two `onBindViewHolder()` methods. The two-parameter one must be implemented, because it is declared as `abstract` in `RecyclerView.Adapter`. You implemented the three-parameter `onBindViewHolder()` method, which is fine, but you still need the two-parameter one.